# SQL code to select records where field_A matches the field_A value of a certain field_B value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```
ID  Email
aa  aa@gmail.com
aa  aa@yahoo.com
bb  bb@gmail.com
cc  cc@hotmail.com
```

Using SQL code, I want to select all records that has the same ID as the ID of email aa@gmail.com. So it will return:

```
aa  aa@gmail.com
aa  aa@yahoo.com
```

I know that we can select records where field_A is a certain value like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ID="aa"
```

How can I modify this code to achieve the desired results?

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: @Strawberry it does not matter what the primary key is. It could be ID or some other column and I still want this code to work.

Comment: As you want it work on any (non-unique) cols note the query with subquery will not give the answer if the subquery returns 2 or more rows.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tablename t
WHERE t.ID = (SELECT t2.id
              FROM tablename t2
              WHERE t2.email = 'aa@gmail.com'
             );
```

Comment: This is my favorite answer. Clean and easy to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from tablename where id in (
    SELECT ID AS count FROM tablename GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `JOIN` the same table `ON ID`, the result is possible:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T2.Email 
FROM TableName T1
JOIN TableName T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID
WHERE T1.Email = 'aa@gmail.com'
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a52ec3db0a9d1307693229a04952ac61)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUBSTRING_INDEX

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ID=SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Email`, '@', 1) and Email='aa@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding it should return values after evaluating

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (ID VARCHAR(5), Email VARCHAR (20));

INSERT INTO TestTable (ID, Email) VALUES
('aa', 'aa@gmail.com'),
('aa', 'aa@yahoo.com'),
('bb', 'bb@gmail.com'),

SELECT *
FROM TestTable
WHERE ID  IN 
(
SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID)>1 THEN ID END AS ID
FROM TestTable
)
```